# Authentication against ADFS with WCF hosted on Windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, adfs2.0, adfs

I have a wcf service that queries ADFS for SAML token. This is a common snippet from web to query ADFS and get back the SAML token.
However it always ends up breaking at the line  **return channel.Issue(rst); . Error is ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported.**
At least at an high level  i am not able to figure out whether the error is at the ADFS server end or with the way WCF service is configured or with code. Please help.

```
public SecurityToken GetSamlToken()
{
    using (var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
        new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
        new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://serv/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed"))))
    {
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;                
        WSTrustChannel channel = null;                
        try
        {
            string KeyType;
            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:xxxx/Service1/mex"),                         
                KeyType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,                                        
            };

            channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();

            return channel.Issue(rst);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (channel != null)
            {
                channel.Abort();
            }
            factory.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with the

```
AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:xxxx/Service1/mex")
```

I replaced it with a relying party uri and it issues me the token. The only issue here being the confusing error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely related to the configuration of the ADFS endpoint.  The following article seems to provide a good overview of ADFS web service communication along with steps to resolve some issues:

http://msinnovations.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/some-tips-on-active-federation-with-adfs-2-0/

In order to obtain more information about where (and perhaps why) the error is occurring, you may want/need to configure WCF tracing/logging.  The following link provides an overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Regards,

Comment: The blog reads "ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported. One of the reasons that this can occur is if you have not setup a relying party trust in ADFS for your application." So does this mean my wcf service has to be added as an relying party ? I am a complete novice to ADFS 2.0. I have seen articles on how to configure a relying party but do we do same for a WCF service ? I haven't got physical access to the ADFS server at this point of time.

Comment: Since you said specifically the ADFS point think i will have to accept yours as the answer